# Authorize.net AcceptUI - prevent scrolling to top of page

Tags: html, css, authorize.net

When clicking the [button](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Integrating_the_Hosted_Payment_Information_Form) to display the payment form in acceptui.js, the scroll jumps to the top of the page. Can this be avoided?

Here's what I have tried:

```
<button type="button"
            id="payment_button"
            class="AcceptUI btn btn-success"
            data-billingAddressOptions='{"show":false, "required":false}' 
            data-apiLoginID="loginId" 
            data-clientKey="clientKey"
            data-acceptUIFormBtnTxt="Submit" 
            data-acceptUIFormHeaderTxt=""
            data-paymentOptions='{"showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": false}' 
            data-responseHandler="paymentResponseHandler"
            onClick="fixScroll();">
                Get Token
        </button>

<script>
    function fixScroll()
        {
            $(window).scrollTop( $('#payment_button').offset().top );
        }

</script>
```

This doesn't work because the show event occurs after the click event.

I was able to do a work around with:

```
 var scroll_top = 0; 
function fixScroll()
{
    scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop(); 

    var target = document.querySelector('#AcceptUIBackground');
    observer.observe(target, {
        attributes: true
    });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    $(window).scrollTop( scroll_top);
});
```

But it still scrolls after entering payment info.

Answer (score 0):

In their example they have:

```
$("#btnOpenAuthorizeNetIFrame").click(function () {
        $("#add_payment").show();
        $("#send_token").attr({ "action": "https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment", "target": "add_payment" }).submit();
        $(window).scrollTop($('#add_payment').offset().top - 50);
            });
```

try to remove the last line:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#add_payment').offset().top - 50);
```

Comment: I'm not sure which example you're referring to, I don't have any code like that on my page.